# Enabling order status "Complete" in overview without Shipment

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, order-status

A customer doesn't want to use the shipping forms (it takes too much time). If there is no shipment for an order it will not go to complete. I tried to solve this by setting the state "Processing" to the status "Complete" so the order would go complete as soon as the invoice is created. Worked so far, until I found out that PayPal autogenerates the invoice.
My idea was to let him set the state to "Complete" manually (And autogenerate all invoices) but this doesn't work if there is no shipment created. 
How could I let him select the "Complete" status manually without shipment? Do you have any other solutions?

Edit: Another idea: Is there a possibility to create the shipments from the overview screen? Like ticking all orders and selecting "Ship" in the dropdown menu on the top right? This would solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:
I wrote a module that creates a mass action "Complete orders" which creates the invoices and shipments for the selected orders from the order overview grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Virtual Product which does not require shipment. That way you can complete the order without coding anything to remove the shipment.

Comment: He has 140 articles in his shop already, most of them configurable, so I can not change them to virtual products :/